# express-session using Redis not working on Heroku

Tags: typescript, express, heroku, redis, express-session

```
// Redis Config
var RedisStore = require('connect-redis')(session);
const Redis = require('ioredis');
const redis = process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production'
    ? new Redis({ host: 'localhost', port: 6379 })
    : new Redis(process.env.REDIS_URL);

server.set('trust proxy', 1)
server.use(session({
    store: new RedisStore({ client: redis }),
    secret: process.env.SESSION_SECRET_KEY ?? '',
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: true,
    cookie: {
        secure: (process.env.NODE_ENV && process.env.NODE_ENV == 'production') ? true : false,
        maxAge: 1000 * 60 * 10
    }
}));
```

I have an issue in my session management using express-session with Redis, It works locally but when I deploy it to Heroku the session is not working. The above snippet code is my configuration for a session with Redis.

In my local the debug logs for `req.session` shows like this:

```
Session {
  cookie: {
    path: '/',
    _expires: 2022-09-26T12:03:55.932Z,
    originalMaxAge: 600000,
    httpOnly: true,
    secure: false
  },
  sfdcAuth: {
    instanceUrl: xxxxxxx,
    accessToken: xxxxxxx
  }
}
```

Below are the debug logs for `req.session` on Heroku:

```
Session { 2022-09-26T11:42:46.855800+00:00 app[web.1]: cookie: { path: '/', _expires: null, originalMaxAge: null, httpOnly: true }
```

Comment: I also don't see "secure: true", maybe the problems is not in functionality but simply logging, can you find the session cookie with expected data in your browser when sending the request?

Comment: In my configuration above I set secure: true when it's in production. On your second question when I check the cookie there's a `connect.sid` and has a random string value.

Comment: is that cookie httpOnly, secure and has path: '/'?

Comment: I believe that is the default configuration cause when I'm checking my config I don't have `httpOnly` and `path`.